# "nor" after a usual negative sentence

Tags: sentence-construction, negation, neither-nor

At the local subway, the announcer says at the last station to the other people:

> "Please do not enter the safety zone ***nor*** attempt to board the
>   train."

I wonder, is ***"nor"*** necessary, optional or incorrect in this context? Could  it be replaced with simple "***or***", or does it change the meaning?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The word "nor" in this context is preferred. The clause "attempt to board the train" is positive.  Preceding it by **or** does not in itself reverse that positive. However, in context of the full sentence, native speakers would know it is meant as negative.

A purpose the **nor** provides is to act as a reminder that the following clause is to be interpreted in the negative.  In other words, "Don't attempt to board the train."

Ideally he might have said:

> Please, neither enter the safety zone nor attempt to board the train.

That said, I see no problem with it as stated.